# summing in sections -teradata sql

Tags: sql, sum, teradata, partition

I have a data set separated by date for example,

```
date          value
10/30/2015      0
10/30/2015      0
10/30/2015      3
10/30/2015      0
10/30/2015      0
1/28/2018       0
1/28/2018       0
1/28/2018       3 
1/28/2018       0
1/28/2018       0
```

and I need to sum these values and sort them into dates so my desired resulting table would be

```
date          value
10/30/2015       3
1/28/2018        3
```

I wasn't sure if I needed to use "rows unbounded preceding" or if I could just sum over date or something similar.

thank you

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if i am using `GROUP BY` with `SUM` ?

```
select date, sum(value) as value
from table t
group by date
order by date;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DATE
    ,SUM(value)
FROM myTable
GROUP BY DATE
ORDER BY DATE ASC
```